# Allow special characters and whitespace only between alphabets using Swift 4

Tags: swift, regex, uitextfield

I want to validate my textfield text only allow `alphabets, Special characters` and `whitespace`. `Special characters` and `whitespace` only between `alphabets` not from initial.

```
For example: 

Textfield Input : 

2345 (Don't Allow)
23&* (Don't Allow)
*(demo (Don't Allow)
de m123 (Don't Allow)
demo (Allow)
de(jm) (Allow)
de mo (Allow)
```

I am using below but not working well

```
"[a-zA-Z\\s]+"
```

Note: Allow only `" / \ ; : . , ( )"` this special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "alphabets" you seem to mean `[a-zA-Z]` ("English letters"). And as best I can understand, you don't mean "symbols and whitespace only between alphabets." You mean "symbols and whitespace only after at least one alphabet."

It's not clear what you mean by "symbols" in this, and whether "symbols and whitespace" is intended to include "all things that are not English letters." If that's what you mean, then it is straightforward:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z /\\;:.,()]*
```

This says: an English letter followed by zero or more other characters. I believe that matches all of your examples. If it doesn't, can you provide an example where it fails?

Comment: 1. You mean "symbols and whitespace only after at least one alphabet - Yes
2. What you mean by "symbols" - I mean special characters

My problem if i give white space only alone into textfield my validation going true. But atleast one character need to enter before white space and same for special characters @Rob Napier

Comment: "Special characters" doesn't provide any greater definition than "symbols." Is ب a letter? Is it a special character? Is it none of the above? Is ‍‍ a "special character?"

Comment: "My problem if i give white space only alone into textfield my validation going true." Yes, my regular expression will address that.

Comment: " / \ ; : . , ( )" this special characters I need to allow others don't allow @Rob Napier

Comment: I have one more doubt how to do allow only alphabets and space, space should be between characters not from initial @Rob Napier

Comment: You need to be precise about your requirements. Do you mean "space should be between characters" or do you mean "space should only be allowed after at least one letter?" Is "x " legal, with a trailing space (i.e. not "between characters"). You also need to be precise about what you mean by "whitespace." Is \t (tab) whitespace? Are NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0), EM SPACE (U+2003), and IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE (U+3000) "whitespace," or just " " (U+0020)? There are 17 different "whitespace" characters in Unicode (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm). Would you reject "de[jm]"?

Comment: I am sorry I am asking if user entered atleast one text after that only we need to allow space. if user give only space without any charters  we don't allow. Also, here I need to allow only alphabets and space.This is I want to learn.

Comment: I believe the above (`^[a-zA-Z].*`) is what you want. If it doesn't work for you, please edit your question with an example of a case that passes or fails when it shouldn't.

Comment: de mo123 (Don't Allow) but your solution allowing @ Rob Napier

Comment: Updated. Note that the double \ isn't really part of the regex; I just expect you'll put it in a `""` string, so it'll need to be quoted.